# base64 img src in WebUI leads to an error

Tags: dart, dart-webui

Here is the problematic part of the template:

```html
<ul id="list">
  <template iterate='file in convertedfiles.files'>
    <li>{{file.filename}}
    <template if='file.isImage'>
      <img src="{{file.src}}" alt="{{file.filename}}"><br/>
      Source: {{file.src}}
     </template>
    </li>
  </template>
</ul>
```

convertedfiles is a list of AndroidFile:

```dart
class AndroidFile {
File _file;  

String filename;
String src;
bool isImage;

AndroidFile(this._file) : isImage = false {
    filename = htmlEscape(_file.name);

    // If the file is an image, read and display its thumbnail.
    if (_file.type.startsWith('image')) {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader();
    reader.on.load.add((e) {
        src = reader.result.toString().trim();

        // prints the correct URL (data:image/png;base64,...)
        print(src);
        isImage = true;  
        watcher.dispatch();
      });

    reader.readAsDataUrl(_file);  
    }
  }
}
```

The template gets displayed. It shows the filename, it shows the source but the imagetag looks like

```html
 <img alt="screenshot-1179.png" src="#">
```

The hash is underlined (in Chromium source view) and if I click on it it says "File not found: /web/out/"

Converted to JS is says in Chrome:
"Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html"

Sample source is on [GitHub](https://github.com/MikeMitterer/AndroidIconGenerator.DART)
 
Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if you know that you are handling a safe URI that is not vulnerable to XSS, you can  work around this problem by using a SafeUri wrapper (imported from `web_ui/web_ui.dart`). For instance, change your template from:

```html
<img src="{{file.src}}" alt="{{file.filename}}">
```

to:

```html
<img src="{{new SafeUri.unsafe(file.src)}}" alt="{{file.filename}}">
```

Or change file.src internally to store a SafeUri.

Comment: Thanks Siggi! Great support.

Comment: In my case (SDK 0.2.9.9_r16323 and WebUI 0.2.9) I had to use: 
import 'package:web_ui/safe_html.dart';
safeuri = new SafeUri.unsafe(src); to store the SafeUri. There is only this named constructor. But with this - it works just perfect.

Comment: It's currently `new SafeUri.unsafe()`. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

It's because the URI gets sanitized for security reasons. The sanitizer turns invalid URIs into a hash `#`.

From `web_ui/templating.dart`:

```dart
/**
 * Ensure that [usiString] is a safe URI. Otherwise, return a '#' URL.
 *
 * The logic in this method was based on the GWT implementation located at:
 * http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/UriUtils.java
 */
String sanitizeUri(uri) {
  if (uri is SafeUri) return uri.toString();
  uri = uri.toString();
  return _isSafeUri(uri) ? uri : '#';
}

const _SAFE_SCHEMES = const ["http", "https", "ftp", "mailto"];

bool _isSafeUri(String uri) {
  var scheme = new Uri(uri).scheme;
  if (scheme == '') return true;

  // There are two checks for mailto to correctly handle the Turkish locale.
  //   i -> to upper in Turkish locale -> İ
  //   I -> to lower in Turkish locale -> ı
  // For details, see: http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/turkish-i18n.html
  return _SAFE_SCHEMES.contains(scheme.toLowerCase()) ||
      "MAILTO" == scheme.toUpperCase();
}
```

So the sanitizer turns your `data:` scheme URI into a `#`. Data URIs can be used for XSS, but as far as I know the check could be improved by allowing data URIs when the data URI content type is `image/*`.

Perhaps file a bug report?

Comment: Here https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues/286 is the issue if someone wants to follow...